# how to get focus to an internal frame in html page

Tags: html, applet, jframe, jinternalframe

How to get focus to a internal jframe inside a jframe when we show our applet on browser and applet start focus automatically go to browser arrow keys do page up and down no my specifiec order that i add to my frame listener?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
protected void createFrame() {

    MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
}
```